# Can ORMLite auto-upgrade a database by dropping and recreating?

Tags: android, sqlite, upgrade, ormlite

We have an ORMLite solution implemented in our current application. We use it for caching results from REST calls from our servers. So, it's not super important that the data be there (or be left over when a user updates the app). We just added an update which created a new column in one of our database-persisted models, `Shift`, and we're now seeing the following exception:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: acknowledged (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM ...
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(SQLiteConnection.java)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1113)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:690)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1430)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1369)
       at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidCompiledStatement.getCursor(AndroidCompiledStatement.java:162)
       at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidCompiledStatement.runQuery(AndroidCompiledStatement.java:57)
       at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator.<init>(SelectIterator.java:55)
       at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.buildIterator(StatementExecutor.java:232)
       at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.query(StatementExecutor.java:181)
       at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.query(BaseDaoImpl.java:263)
```

I checked to make sure this field was added to the ORMLite configuration file, and it was, so I'm not sure what's happening here. I thought that ORMLite will drop the database and re-create it if it finds that the schema has changed (and you don't add an `onUpgrade()` method to the `DatabaseHelper`), but I'm now thinking I'm incorrect.

How do I fix this? I've tried reading through the ORMLite manual, but either I glossed over the section about default upgrade behavior or I didn't find it...

Comment: http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_4.html#Use-With-Android states you must implement both `onCreate` and `onUpgrade`

Comment: Apparently we _do_ implement `onUpgrade`, but I guess what I was getting at is: "Can I just drop the entire database in `onUpgrade()` and make it recreate itself?"

Answer (score 3):

> I thought that ORMLite will drop the database and re-create it if it finds that the schema has changed (and you don't add an onUpgrade() method to the DatabaseHelper), but I'm now thinking I'm incorrect.

You are incorrect.  ORMLite does not have any magic code that handles schema updating.  Check out the docs for [upgrading your schema](http://ormlite.com/docs/upgrade-schema) from the manual.  To quote:

> When you upgrade your application, you may have to add columns or make other changes to the data that was stored by previous versions of your application. If you are on Android then in your DatabaseHelper, there should be an onUpgrade() method that extends the following method from the OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.
>
> ```
> abstract void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database,
> ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
> ```
>
> In that method you can use your DAO to perform any tweaks to the schema:
>
> ```
> Dao<Account, Integer> dao = getHelper().getAccountDao();
> // change the table to add a new column named "age" 
> dao.executeRaw("ALTER TABLE `account` ADD COLUMN age INTEGER;");
> ```

So you will need to do the upgrading yourself.  The docs also show how you can use the database version numbers to make specific changes based on which database version your client has.

If you don't care about the existing tables then the `onUpgrade(...)` method can just drop the tables and call `onCreate(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

ORMLite is just a wrapper for Android SQLite so you can upgrade your database same as you upgrade your SQLite database.

It can be done in three simple steps

1. Just add sql script files in assest or make it as resource then name them which help to select appropriate db version for changes you have made in database
2. Determine any version changes and pick appropriate  script file
3. Read script file line by line and execute sql script on db

You are done!

Answer (score 0):

I use this code for onUpgrade for case when no need to transfer data from old version to new one. I think i will help you

```
@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        try {
            TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, YourRecord.class, true);
            // Drop other tables here
            onCreate(database, connectionSource);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```